# Session всегда является null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, сессия

уважаемые форумчани!

Столкнулся с глупой проблемой, когда вроде как инициализировал Session, но в другой части когда, Session все равно null.

Вот как я инициализирую:

```
 if (isAuto)
 {
     Session["UserID"] = sendedUser.Id;
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Vocabularies");
 }
```

Вот как я к нему обращаюсь:

```
public VocabulariesController()
    {
        var valueSession = Session["UserID"];
        userID = Int32.Parse(valueSession.ToString());
        _vocabularyContext = new VocabularyContext();
    }
```

Что я делаю не так? Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Был предпринят ряд решений, каждый из которых мог равноценно повлиять на решение проблемы:

1. В `Global.asax` был добавлен такой кусок кода:

   ```
   protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Session["init"] = 0;
   }
   ```
2. Была включена в ручную служба `ASP.NET State Service`
3. Код инициализации `userID` был перенесен из конструктора в функцию.